# Shift final given number of elemts to front of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an array

```
var itemsArr = ["blue", "wine", "orange", "yellow", "cyan"];
```

How can I get a certain amount of array elements from the END to the FRONT of the array?

Expected output:

example 1:

```
//shift final 3 elements
var expected = ["orange", "yellow", "cyan", "blue", "wine"];
```

example 2:

```
//shift final 2 elements
var expected = ["yellow", "cyan", "blue", "wine", "orange"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination with [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
var itemsArr = ["blue", "wine", "orange", "yellow", "cyan"];

itemsArr = itemsArr.splice(-3).concat(itemsArr);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(itemsArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

itemsArr = itemsArr.splice(3).concat(itemsArr);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(itemsArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: How would it be if I need to do it in reverse? e.g. set FRONT 3 to the END?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

[JSBin Example](https://jsbin.com/lelexa/3/edit?js,console)

```
var a = ["blue", "wine", "orange", "yellow", "cyan"];

function shifter(arr, n) {
  var shifted = arr.splice(-n);
  return shifted.concat(arr);
}


console.log(shifter(a, 3));
```

Comment: How can I do it the other way around? e.g. set FRONT 3 to the END?

Comment: super easy, just take the negative off of the `n` in the function on line 2

Answer (score 1):

```
function moveToFront(x, noFromEnd){
    if(noFromEnd > x.length){
        alert("Immpossible");
    }
    else if(noFromEnd == x.length){
        return x;
    }
    else if(noFromEnd < 0){
        alert("immpossible")
    }
    else if(noFromEnd == 0){
        return x;
    }
    else{
        var returnArray = []
        for(var i=(x.length-noFromEnd);i<x.length;i++){
            returnArray.push(x[i])
        }
        for(var i=0; i<(x.length-noFromEnd); i++){
            returnArray.push(x[i])
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```